# Transloco merge local with serverside translation objects

Tags: angular, internationalization, transloco

I am looking for a robust way to prefetch a translation file from a server, and merge with the local translation file during app initialization.

The docs state that you can set the translation language using an `APP_INITIALIZER` provider
https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/recipes/prefetch

This may work if you only have a static json asset file (e.g. `src/assets/i18n/en.json`), but I can't make this work combining with a json translation fetched from a server.

Here is my attempt at using the app initializer :

```
// app.module.ts 
...
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      useFactory: preloadServer,
      deps: [TranslocoService, HttpClient]
    }
...
```

```
export function preloadUser(transloco: TranslocoService, _httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    combineLatest([
      _httpClient.get(`http://my.server.com/en.json`), // fetches a remote translation
      transloco.selectTranslation('en') // fetches the local static asset file
    ]).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(([server, client]) => (
        Object.assign(client, server) // Merges the 2 objects
      )),
      tap(merged => transloco.setTranslation(merged, 'en')) // Updates the 'en' translation with the merged object
    ).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Weird thing is that this randomly works. If I reload the app 10 times, half of the times I'll see the server translations and half the client translations.

**Update**

After @naren-murali 's answer, I realized that I can re-write the app initializer function to utilize the transloco API which provides a translation merge option, so I am adding my updated approach

```
export function preloadTranslation(transloco: TranslocoService, httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    return concat(
      transloco.selectTranslation('en'), // This fetches the local translation
      httpClient.get(`http://my.server.com/en.json`) // This fetches the server translation
    ).pipe(
      // Merge the server keys into the local object using the transloco API option "{ merge: true }"
      tap(serverTranslation => transloco.setTranslation(serverTranslation, 'en', { merge: true }))
    ).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try returning the `combineLatest` maybe that is what's missing!

```
export function preloadUser(transloco: TranslocoService, _httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return () => {
    return combineLatest([ //                        <-- changed here!
      _httpClient.get(`http://my.server.com/en.json`), // fetches a remote translation
      transloco.selectTranslation('en') // fetches the local static asset file
    ]).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(([server, client]) => (
        Object.assign(client, server) // Merges the 2 objects
      )),
      tap(merged => transloco.setTranslation(merged, 'en')) // Updates the 'en' translation with the merged object
    ).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... :)
So what happened here, is that the promise did resolve, but the initializer did not wait for it (because I didn't return properly), so it randomly resolved before or after the default language was loaded from the local asset file ?

Comment: @ktsangop I think the promise ran without the return which caused it to work sometimes, but without the return there is a high chance of a timing issue since it does not wait for the promise

Comment: @ktsangop it happens to all of us ! :)

Comment: Being used to RxJs, I always have in mind that it needs a subscription or it just won't work, but Promises are out of control :P

Comment: @ktsangop yeah!